# How to get query result in multiple columns in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am new to Postgres. I have a table which has the data in the below format:

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io1Zy.png)

And I want it in the following format. Any help would be appreciated.

[Output Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOPKC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a self-join:

```
SELECT table_2184."Value" as "2184",
       table_2095."Value" as "2095",
       table_2184."Date_Time"
FROM table AS table_2184
JOIN table AS table_2095 ON table_2184."Date_Time" = table_2095."Date_Time"
WHERE table_2184."Tag_ID" = 2184
  AND table_2095."Tag_ID" = 2095;
```

Basically, you alias the table so you can join it to itself.  If it's not always guaranteed that the tags exist at the same timestamp, you may want to use a FULL OUTER JOIN instead of a JOIN.  In that case, also move the WHERE condition to the join.